# Imitating cookies behavior in chrome packed app

Tags: javascript, sockets, cookies, google-chrome-app

I am using REST service, that is not in my control to modify.
The service have verification/login and many "data-retrive" endpoints.

I have been requested to create "Chrome packed app" that will use this REST service.

**The limitations I have are:**
Can't use sandboxed pages.
Can't use webview.

**The problem:**

1. Xhr requests ignore "Set-cookie" headers.
2. it's impossible to set cookies manually (Like there is no cookie api).

**Ideas & research**

1. I googled my way into XHR implementation using "chrome.socket", With no https support, since "chrome.socket" dose not support TLS.
2. Forge is a "Chrome-js" library that adds TLS support to the "chrome.socket"

**Questions**

1. Is there any way to Modify requests and response headers?
2. Is there any way to combine the XHR implementation using "chrome.socket" with Forge? (I don't really know the protocol or the original XHR implementation)
3. is it even reasonable to implement fake cookie API to manage the data from the headers?

Comment: And why exactly can't you use webview?

Comment: Because i need to use webview within the application. and you can't do nasted webviews.

Comment: Do you need to set arbitrary cookies on your request, or do you just need to return the cookies that the service sent to you earlier (i.e. the way cookies are supposed to work)? A REST API that requires setting arbitrary cookies from scratch would be pretty strange.

Comment: No no, not from scratch, just want a browser-like cookie behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using a [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (CORS) request. There is a good introduction [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

In particular, you will need to use `withCredentials`:

> Standard CORS requests do not send or set any cookies by default. In
>   order to include cookies as part of the request, you need to set the
>   XMLHttpRequest’s .withCredentials property to true: [...]

Note that you will need the server's cooperation to do this:

> In order for this to work, the server must also enable credentials by
>   setting the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header to
>   “true”.

Since you are always on Chrome, you could use the [Fetch API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch?hl=en) instead of XMLHttpRequest2. In that case you would add the `credentials` option:

> Should you want to make a fetch request with credentials such as
>   cookies, you should set the credentials of the request to “include”.

Both of these mechanisms will (1) support HTTPS and (2) manage cookies opaquely, i.e. they will not permit you to inspect the cookie data.

Comment: I think your might be on some thing, Checking it out.

Comment: Many thanks @rhashimoto. It's was huge miss on my side.